# Where is the option for grease pencil convert to curve 2.78a

Tags: grease-pencil

I have drawn a few lines holding the <kbd>D</kbd> key. Now I want to convert it to a path or a curve but I can't find these options in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>). Where are these options in Blender 2.78a?
[image: properties panel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is not in the properties panel (<kbd>N</kbd>) but in the tools panel (<kbd>T</kbd>). Open it up and scroll down to the *Grease Pencil* tab on the left. At the bottom of the *Grease Pencil* panel you can find *Convert to Geometry...*. Click it and you can choose whether you want to convert it to a polygon curve, a path or a bezier curve.

[image: tools panel]

Comment: Thanks to find me out It has many settings down. Few seconds before just I have press search bar and type grease pencil convert and enter and then a pop-up path, curve or mesh i have done that way but any way thanks for finding

Comment: Good to know: After the conversion has been done, nothing seems to have changed, the GP stroke is still visible and hides the object created by the conversion. In the 3D View Properties Panel (`N`) uncheck `Grease Pencil Layers` (or hide individual layers in the list). Be aware each click on the conversion button has created an object, so you may have multiple objects on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Convert Grease Pencil Operator]

You can press **space key** in the 3D View to bring up the **operator search menu** and then type **Convert Grease Pencil** and enter. Then choose the options for conversion.