# Animate objects following a grease pencil stroke?

Tags: animation, tracking, grease-pencil

Hi there my question is can you animate something on top of your grease pencil stroke? Make it act like a train track and your default cube as the train. The cube element would just move on the grease pencil stroke from beginning to end? I know python I just needed to be pointed to the right direction to get started.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to do that on a grease pencil stroke directly or not, but you could convert (a copy of) the grease pencil stroke to a bezier curve and make it follow that.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thank you this comment helped a lot, if you want to post this as an answer I will pick this as best answer.

Comment: Done, posted below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to use a *Grease Pencil* stroke directly as animation path.

What you could try instead is convert the desired grease pencil stroke to a *Bezier Curve* object and use it instead.

If you need the original grease pencil try converting a copy of it instead, so you can keep both intact.

[This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67573/where-is-the-option-for-grease-pencil-convert-to-curve-2-78a) describes how you can do it in more detail.